# CentOS - Find out which user spawned process after sudo su

Tags: linux, centos

Im logged in a Linux CentOS via ssh. There is a process that has been running for some time and i can find its PID via

> htop

plus fn+f4 and typing the name of the file that spawned the process or

> ps -aux | grep <file_that_spawned_the_process>

Both methods show me that the user that spawned the process is <Some_User>, however i am pretty sure that it was <Some_Other_User> via

> sudo -u <Some_User> ./<file_that_spawned_the_process>

I want to find out who is <Some_Other_User>, if there is some other user at all. Finding out from which machine (I.P.) did he log into the CentOS host would also be appreciated.

I read all .bash_history from all users but couldnt find anything that suggested usage of sudo su <Some_Other_User>. I found some answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598001/how-do-you-find-the-original-user-through-multiple-sudo-and-su-commands) but it doesnt seem to be what im looking for.
Does anyone have any suggestions? Everything i found is about either finding out which is my original user or about finding out which user (not original) spawned a process, but a combination of both doesnt seem trivial to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `pstree -u` ...

This should show you the uid transitions.
I just did a test against a box, launching `top` via `su - user2 -c top` ....

```
        |-sshd-+-sshd---sshd(user2)---bash---screen
        |      `-sshd---sshd(user1)---sudo(root)---su---top(user2)
```

Comment: Curious... i ran it with every process started by the <Some_User> and it just returned something like 
ProcessName(SomeUser)─┬─caRepeater
                          └─158*[{ProcessName}]
Should this necessarily mean that my suspicions are wrong?

Comment: Just to be clearer, the suspicions i meant were about the process being initialized by another "disguised" user via sudo -u

Comment: Off the top of my head I can't think of a way to NOT have *some_other_user* show up in the chain of the pstree output.  If they have full sudoers access to the box, and you don't ship audit-logs off to a machine where they don't they might have used other methods and cleaned up their trails, though. E.g. doing what you describe via an `at` command and then remove the lines where they switched user from the logs.